# Something in my visual studio solution causes the windows busy cursor to constantly spin and never stop, how do I find what is causing this issue?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have several solutions that includes a web project using ASP.NET.  They are all similar to each other, but for different websites.  Some of the time when I open one of the solutions in VS, and all of the time when I open more that one of the solutions in different instances of Visual Studio, the Windows busy cursor appears, with the spinning blue circle.  The blue circle flickers in out rapidly while the white arrow remains constant.  Wherever I move the cursor on my three monitors, this remains.  Only when I pass the cursor over the code window portion of the GUI does the blue spinning and flickering circle go away.  It never stops, I have left the computer running over a weekend and the same thing will be there Monday morning.  Only when I close Visual Studio down, whichever one I opened most recently, will the spinning wheel disappear.

This had been happening for several years, and it was happening in VS 2017 and VS 2019.  I thought it was just something wrong with that machine.  But I just got a brand new PC, and as soon as I installed VS 2019 and pulled down the code, it started happening.  So it does not appear to be anything hardware-related, or even a problem with some older update to Windows as I have a fresh new install.

The issue must be something in my projects or the solution, but I do not know how to track it down.  I have tried looking at the Task Manager but I don't see any abnormal CPU loads or memory commitments.  Programs seem to run fine and at the usual speed.  It's just the very distracting blinking cursor that I have had to put up with for years.  Does anybody have any recommendations for looking at my project and tracking down what is causing this?

These websites use an older CMS called Ektron, which requires a large number of files to be included with the project, but I can't just remove them.  Besides, I am not sure why that would cause a problem, they are just a collection of files and scripts and I don't know why anything would be getting loaded, but I am not an expert with Visual Studio.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked only with native code, not managed.  Here are reasons I've seen long delays or busy icons in Visual Studio:

1. A corrupt or confused Intellisense database.

   Option A:  Close all instances of Visual Studio, delete the Intellisense database files (location and naming depends on the VS version).  Re-open the solution in Visual Studio.  It will spend some time rebuilding the database but then should be fine after that.

   Option B:  In Tools > Options, try turning off everything related to Intellisense, Code Browsing, "Code Squiggles", etc.
2. You have two instances of VS trying to open the same solution, and one of them tries for a long time to get access to the Intellisense database behind held by the other.  Close both instances.
3. You're debugging and the debugger is trying to load symbols (PDB files) from an unresponsive symbol server.  In Debug > Options > Debugging > Symbols, turn off automatic loading of symbols.  (You can always load them on demand.)  Also ensure you have a local symbol cache with plenty of disk space.
4. You're debugging an application with several threads and you have accidentally checked the feature that tries to show you the locations of all threads each time you break into the debugger.  This can cause infuriatingly slow debugging sessions.  On the toolbar, there's a button with an icon of a red line twisted together with a blue one.  Make sure that button is not selected if you don't need that feature.
5. Corporate scanners/monitors/loggers installed on your machine by your IT group to watch for malware, to whitelist programs, and to detect suspicious behavior often hook the OS at a very low level that can slow down and serialize i/o operations.  Work with your IT folks to temporarily disable those applications and see if the problem remains.  If the problem goes away, perhaps you can get an exception for one of those or have your IT people work with the vendor to improve them.

I'll make this a community wiki so others can add their possible causes here.

Comment: I have looked into all 5 of these peroposed solutions and unfortunately none of them helped.  While this is an older solution, about 7 years old, I am on a brand new machine with a brand new installation of VS 2019, and the same thing is happening as on my old machine.  I deleted the Intellisense files and let them rebuild just to be sure, but that did not help, and I tried the others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this too. It had bound a huge ItemsSource to a WPF ListView. First the app started, then the round Wait Cursor turned for more than 10 seconds. During this time you could click on stuff and some things were responding, others not. It was the rendering thread of the content of this ListView that caused the busy cursor. Once I deleted 90% of the bound data it behaved normally again. Nothing wrong with WPF, I just could not locate the origin of the busy cursor for a long time because even that the app was in break mode it didn't show the rendering thread as such.